# Using same output ID on different tabs in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am new in R and R shiny but I have a shiny tool where I would like to call a box output element on two other tabs in the dashboardBody. However, because shiny only allows the use of unique IDs, I am trying to use shiny modules to overcome this. However, after creating my UI and Server, the element does appear on one menuItem but I still cannot figure out why it does not appear on the other menuItems.

Here is the code I used hoping it will display the output element on the second menuItem;

```
ui <- settingsUI ('prog_vs_real_radio_week_month1') #here is the ID I intend to call on the second menu item
server <- function(input, output, session) {
settingsServer('prog_vs_real_radio_week_maand1', prog_vs_real_radio_week_month ,  type = 'occupancy')} #occupanycy here is the id of the menuItem where I will want to have the box outputelement
```

Here is the entire code for the module I came up with;

```
settingsUI <- function(id) {
  tagList(
   box(NS(id)),
   box(NS(id, "prog_vs_real_radio_week_month"))
)
}
  
settingsServer <- function(id, prog_vs_real_radio_week_month, type) {
   moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
      output$prog_vs_real_radio_week_month <- renderUI({
         filter(menuItem == type)
         conditionalPanel(
              condition = paste('input.difficulty >=', 
                                  difficulty$prog_vs_real_weergave),
              box(
                title = "Weergave", width = 3,
                uiOutput('prog_vs_real_radio_week_month')
                )
              )
          })
      })
  }

ui <- settingsUI ('prog_vs_real_radio_week_month1')
server <- function(input, output, session) {
settingsServer('prog_vs_real_radio_week_month1', prog_vs_real_radio_week_month ,  type = 'occupancy')}
```

Comment: IDs in `settingsUI` and `settingsServer` do not match.